# Can anyone explain the role of some of these blocks in this PV inverter system?

Tags: power-electronics, simulation, solar-cell, matlab, simulink

I get the role of following blocks:
1)MPPT controller (is a matlab function code of Perturb and observe)
2)boost converter
3)H-bridge inverter and its PI controller.

I don't get the role and working of:
1)Battery Switches
2)Unipolar Switching
3)Flyback Converter

Here are the images from simulink model. simulink model credit: Dr. Razman Ayop https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gMoUZgBHy8Y
the video doesn't explain much. simulink file is attached in the video's description.

[image]

[image]

[[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The batteries can be charged or discharged. The switching selects this.

The DC rail voltage needs to be converted to the mains peak voltage and be able to vary it. This is what the flyback converter is used for.

The ‘unipolar’ switching is the pwm logic for the h-bridge in order to generate the mains waveform.

Answer (score 0):

> 1)Battery Switches

Relay protection for battery Charge (Ch) and Discharge (Dch)

> 2)Unipolar Switching

I believe it is the port for modulating the DCAC inverter with an "Amplitude modulation Index"  It must have some conversion rule.

> 3)Flyback Converter

DCDC converter

This stores energy in an inductor with multiple coupled coils for Amp-seconds of charge to be released in each cycle with some primary-secondary ratio, and transfer the current stored into a capacitive load with many rules for load regulation,  stability, overshoot on each cycle thermal rise from losses and margin to overcurrent saturation which loses all the L storage capacity and turns into just a very hot resistor.

Comment: more very fuzzy videos (??) https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/91495-boost-converter-controlled-using-fuzzy-logic-controller